# How to check if a specific port is open for OUTPUT mode?

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables

I'm playing with `iptables` on Linux, and I created some rules to allow only port 53 to send packets:

```
 iptables -P INPUT DROP

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I would like to check if port 53 is actually able to send data to another computer (or maybe I misunderstood the role of a port. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [outgoing port tester](http://portquiz.net/) opening *telnet* like this:

```
telnet portquiz.net 53
```

And wait for the response (or error).

You can also use your browser clicking [here](http://portquiz.net:53).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get no response so I guess the rule I used to accept the OUTPUT on port 53 is not correct...

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it clicking the check mark below the number.

Comment: Just did it, but do you know why the 2nde rule for outbound connection with port 53 does not work ?

Comment: Sorry. After checking that the port is not working, you can make a new question asking why (include a link to this question) and the right way to accomplish your goal.